# Can't install nvidia drivers on a 2 card laptop for xubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xubuntu

I just installed xubuntu 14.04 on an asus gl771j laptop. 
It comes with an integrated intel video card and another nvidia 860m video card.
I open the additional drivers setting window and I get "no additional drivers available"
[image]

I got as far as getting this information, but that's it

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:53 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

How can I install the nvidia drivers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried disabeling the onboard graphics card in the bios/uefi?

Comment: Like @Pabi said, you probably need to change discrete graphics to be the default over integrated. I'm pretty sure Ubuntu doesn't do switchable graphics, so hopefully you have this option.

Comment: if ubuntu doesn't do switchable graphics, is there a distro that does?

Comment: This problem should be resolveable in ubuntu, just let us know if there is no option to turn it off.

Comment: no, i don't see a option in bios setup to turn the intel card off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

First I thought maybe the problem was the Intel card driver. So I downloaded it from them, but then I saw that 14.04 was not a supported distro.

So I've installed 15.04 (even if I prefer LTS) and now I see this:
[image]
I haven't restarted yet :P

Comment: seems to have worked!